# Accessing Windows VMs on Linux hosts remotely

Tags: iptables, firewall

At one of my work sites, we have a set of Linux servers, one of which acts as the main router. On another Linux server inside the network, I'm running Server 2012 in a VM. The Remote Desktop of the VM is turned on, and I can RDP from inside my network. My goal is to use RDP from outside the network, go through the router (Linux box), then go to port 3389 on the other Linux server.

All the servers are using IPTABLES for the firewall, and they are all running Debian Wheezy x64.

I have the following rule in my iptables list: `-A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.15:3389`. The VM is hosted on the 0.15 address, and I want to connect via port 9999 from the outside world. In my tests, it seems like the Remote Desktop Connection is just dropping the connection for no reason. What else can I look for?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't setup a VPN? Exposing RDP (or any remote access technology) to the internet is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thinking about it, you're probably right, @Zypher. How about I rephrase the question to "I want to access a service on port 12345 from the outside world". Would that work instead?

Comment: Yea, also add in what you have tried so far and exactly what issues you are running into. Posts that just ask "How do I do this?" Don't do so well here. They are the equivalent of "gimmie-teh-codez" questions on SO

Comment: @Zypher I edited the question to mention what I tried, from websites I have tried looking for information on. Hopefully this fits a bit better in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was going about this the incorrect way.

First off, if I'm sending the port to `:3389`, it needs to point to the VM's own IP address. If I point to the IP address of the VM's *host*, I need to put it to the VirtualBox RDP port for that VM instance (i.e. `:5050`).

What I did was try to attach to the VM's RDP port directly, instead of the VirtualBox RDP port. I did this so I would have the VM *know* it was being remoted into. I put this line in my iptables config file:

`-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.6:3389`

I restarted iptables, and then I could connect properly. Due to the advice I was given though, it was shortly taken down. I'll be investigating the VPN solution, so as to ensure it's more secure from drive-by RDP'ers.